# Javascript function synchronisation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, undefined, user-input, angular-promise

I'm currently working on a final year project for college. I'm making a UI which gets data from the database, and then manipulates the data using user input to generate a graph.

The order of events is : DataCtrl uses HTTP get to get data from the database. This then stores the data in a dataFactory. Then the RadioCtrl will look for user inputs for selections. This is then stored in the userFactory.

What I want to do is create a function to compare the data from the dataFactory with the input from the userFactory, however it keeps coming up that the dataFactory is undefined. I understand I need to implement some sort of promise / delay, but I've never used either, and I'm learning Javascript on the fly so I'm not too sure how to do this or if it's the best way to go about it. My code is below, any questions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
app.factory('dataFactory', function() {
var data = [];
var ids = [];
var areas = [];
var speakers = [];
var nonSpeakers = [];
var notStated = [];
var highestEd = [];
var gender = [];
var labourPop = [];

//Array of functions for data
var dataService = {};

dataService.getData = function(response) {
    data.push(response);
    response.forEach(function(element){
        ids.push(element.id);
        areas.push(element.area);
        labourPop.push(element.labourPop);
        speakers.push(element.irishSpeakers);
        nonSpeakers.push(element.nonIrishSpeakers);
        notStated.push(element.notStated);
        highestEd.push(element.highestEd);
        gender.push(element.gender);
    })
};

dataService.list = function(){
    return data;
}
return dataService;
});

app.factory('userFactory', function (){
var education;
var gender;
var location;
var graph;
//Add user input functions here
var userService = {
};

userService.filter = function(dataFactory) {

     dataFactory.ids.forEach(function(element){
        if(education ===dataFactory.highestEd[element])
            graph.push(dataFactory.data[element]);
    })

    console.log(dataFactory.ids);
};

return userService;
});

app.controller('GraphCtrl', function(dataFactory, userFactory){
userFactory.filter(dataFactory);
});

app.controller ('DataCtrl', function(dataFactory, $http) {
$http.get("http://localhost:6698/ngdemo/rest/users")
.then(function(response) {
    dataFactory.getData(response.data);
})
});

app.controller('RadioCtrl', function(userFactory) {
userFactory.education = {
    education : ''
};
userFactory.gender = {
    gender : ''
};
userFactory.location = {
        location : ''
};      
});
```

Comment: Code inside a .then() gets called after everything else. It might be that your comparison code is running before dataFactory.getData(response.data). The solution would be to start the comparison inside .then() after dataFactory.getData(response.data).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

to your **app.js** then your html should look like this:

```
    <html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="DataCtrl">

  </body>


</html>
```

Comment: I already have a working website. I was just showing the code relevant to the user input. This is completely unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ***Promise***

```
var compare = new Promise( function(resolve, reject){
  // here goes synchronous code

  if ( /* compare string */ ) {
    resolve( data );
  } else {
    reject( error );
  }
});

compare.then( function(data){
  /* do something with data */
}).catch( function( error ){
  throw new Error( error )
});
```

Comment: What is data in this example? I've seen similar examples online but in my situation, I've retrieved the data from the database previous to doing the comparison, so I don't know what I'm resolving on. Similarly, in the .then function, that's where I would intuitively be doing my comparison, because the data is definitely there (and not undefined).